# Create formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, ifs, index-match

what is my formula if I have this actual data:

Given data is: Smoker and value is 2.1

I have this table:

[image]

If a person is a non-smoker and the result is below 3, the result is "Action Limit", if greater than 5 and non-smoker, the result is Relocation Limit.

ifs and index match formula

Answer (score 0):

If you have `XLOOKUP()` then try it-

```
=XLOOKUP(D6,XLOOKUP(C6,G2:I2,G3:I4),G3:G4,,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(C5,FILTER(B2:C3,B5=B1:C1),A2:A3,,1)
```

---